# Changing order of appearance for feature class with multiple overlapping polygons in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, overlapping-features

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a feature class with many overlapping polygons.   I am changing the transparency of each of the symbols individually so that you can see through each polygon to the underlying features,  much like it would appear if they were 2 different feature classes.

How do I make the underlying polygon appear on top of, instead of underneath, the larger polygon?

Screenshot example embedded below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the "Primary Symbology" pane, select the "Symbol Layer Drawing button"(at the top of the pane, looks kind of like a #). There, you click the switch to enable and you can change the order your symbology draws in.